# Ajax call return head elements of page: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Tags: jquery, json

I have to add jquery at page head:

```
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
</head>
```

On ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'an_action',
                form_data: form_data

                },
            context: this,
        }).done(function(json){
           this.submit_form(jQuery.parseJSON(json));
        });
```

it returns head elements with json output and
Getting following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1
> column 1 of the JSON data

**If I include head section script library at bottom of page then JSON output is fine.**

Comment: Check the network tab for the *actual* response and maybe add `console.log(json)` before you try to parse it so you can see what it *actually* is.  Please include in the question (at least a sample of) the `json` before you parse it

Comment: @freedomn-m The Json output included with Script tags under head section above that causing error

Comment: @freedomn-m its custom php code, no framework